# can a web page be manipulated through ajax from new window?

Tags: php, jquery

Hi... I want to know that when a user posts a comment to my site ... to open a web page (in new window, with a fixed width and height like `window.open` ) which contains the form and after submit, I want to close that windows and show that comment in the parent page through ajax ... (or i guess after closing that window, to auto reload the parent page ... I don't know ) ...

Is there any solution to this .. ?
Or what is the best way to open a pop-up which contains the form (not a new window) ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: A popular aproach is modal window (for example with jQuery). Google it and you will find millions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Attach an onclick handler on whatever you use to let the user make a comment
2. This handler pops up the new window with the form
3. The form submits the comment to the server via ajax
4. Once the ajax handler is done on the server, it returns the comment's ID to the form window script
5. the form window script calls a function in the original window, passing in the comment ID, telling the window to load up the new comment  (via another AJAX call, or directly passing the comment details from the form page)
6. the form page script then closes the window.

Comment: That's up to you. We're here to help, not do it for you. If you had a specific question about some part of all this, that'd be fine. But we're not going to write the whole system fo ryou.

Comment: No i don;t want to write the code for me .. .but i don't understand pct no 5. (the form window script calls a function in the original window, passing in the comment ID, telling the window to load up the new comment (via another AJAX call, or directly passing the comment details from the form page)) how on earth can i do that ?? using what ... thanks very much

Comment: the child window can call `window.opener.YourCommentUpdateFunction()`

Comment: and what data does it sends ...ok i use `window.opener.YourComment(id)` ??

Comment: That's up to you. Pass in whatever you want to trigger an update of the main page.

Answer (score 1):

1. on the popup window form tag add target="_PARENT"
2. on the popup window change the submit button to normal button.
3. on the popup window, when button clicked, submit the form with js and close the window.

document.formname.submit();
this.close();

in this case your popup window is just to get data then the data will be posted to the main window...

Comment: does this work ? all along ? since when ... i did'n know that ... so how is the data parsed to the main page from the opened window .. using `$_POST[] or $_GET[]` in php or only in Javascript ?

Comment: $_POST[] on main window, it works as it works with normal window.

Comment: COOOL ... I did'n know that ... wow .. what tutorial is used for this in that website cause i couldn't find ... thanks a lot

Comment: sorry i have no reference for that. i just examined long ago.. and also thanks for your greets

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent window by using the `window.opener` JavaScript property. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.opener)

Comment: `window.opener` can do that ?

Comment: can you be more explicit please ?

Comment: you can use it to call a function in the parent window that will reload the comments

Comment: can you post online reference ? or a tiny example ... of basic stuff ? thank you very much

Comment: Marc B has the solution basically spelled out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a new window? Why not a modal form? Take a look at this basic [jQuery modal form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html).